# What is a JUnit test case, and how would I go about writing one?

Tags: java, junit

In class, we learned about test cases in Java. The professor didn't go over them that well and all the sources I found online weren't helpful as much. I understand that they help to catch any bugs in the porgram, but how does it work? In the example in class, the professor had something like:

```
@Test
public void test1(){
Webpage n = new Webpage("www.facebook.com");
asssertequals(n.getURL(), "www.facebook.com");

}
```

Is it okay for getURL and Webpage to be used even though the actual code it hasn't been written yet (she wants us to always write our test cases before we code)? When writing a test case, do we write it as if we have written the whole code before, and test whatever values we think will pass or fail? I have alot of questions, I know.

Also, just to be clear on my understanding, the variable n is set equal to whatever Webpage has between its parentheses, but the new operator creates the object that is supposed to be assigned to n.

Comment: Have you read the documentation in the ```junit``` tag that yourself added to this question? There's a link there [Junit Tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/t2framework/wiki/JUnitQuickTutorial). I would start there.

Comment: Also, you might be interested in [Unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) and/or [test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) in general

Comment: Read up on Test Driven Development. The basic idea is that you write some tests to test your code *before* writing any code (obviously all your tests will fail at this point!). Then, you write some code until all your tests pass and (assuming you have rigorous enough tests) you now have a working system! The tests then help ensure that when you start adding new features, you don't break anything that was previously working.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so to start of Test cases are especially good and important for larger projects. As this is automated testing it saves developer sh*t loads of time ;).

```
@Test
public void test1(){
    Webpage n = new Webpage("www.facebook.com"); 
    asssertequals(n.getURL(), "www.facebook.com");
}
```

So first is first:

```
@Test
```

this annotations is used so the compiler knows which methods are actual tests.

```
Webpage n = new Webpage("www.facebook.com");
```

In here you are simply declaring variable "n" to be url (facebook)

```
asssertequals(n.getURL(), "www.facebook.com");
```

This is where the magic happens. assertequals checks if the variable equals to what we expect. If they are equal in this case test passes. but if you had this

```
Webpage n = new Webpage("www.facebook.co.uk"); 
asssertequals(n.getURL(), "www.facebook.com");
```

Then the test will simply fail because expect www.facebook.com but we give co.uk

There are also plenty of other asserts you can use for testing 
[image]

Also for more info refer to this website: i have found it particularly well organized and written as well as easy to understand

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_overview.htm